# How to filter a string using c# using the logic of LIKE in SQL?

Tags: c#, string, filter

I have a string variable in C# aka product_name, I want to filter like this and have it return true or false:

```
product_name LIKE '%BONUS NAME%'
```

How can I do that please?

PS: I have to do it on C# not SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(product_name.Contains("BONUS NAME"))
    // do stuff..
```

Answer (score 14):

**Simple Option: use String.Contains**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.contains.aspx

Example from the MSDN page

```
// This example demonstrates the String.Contains() method
using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    string s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    string s2 = "fox";
    bool b;
    b = s1.Contains(s2);
    Console.WriteLine("Is the string, s2, in the string, s1?: {0}", b);
    }
}
/*
This example produces the following results:

Is the string, s2, in the string, s1?: True
*/
```

**More robust: use regex library**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx

Regular expressions give you much more power, but you can mimic SQL's wildcards with regex operators '.' and '*'

```
string text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string pat = @"fox";

// Instantiate the regular expression object.
Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
Match m = r.Match(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way of matching a part of a string is by using the `IndexOf` method:

```
string input = "This is My FuLl string";
string lookFor = "full";
bool foundIt = input.IndexOf(lookFor, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

Unlike `Contains` this opens up for case insensitive matching.